# Video is not playing completely in auto slider

Tags: jquery, html

I want to video in auto slider.But it is not playing completely.It moves to next slide before completing video.My code is...

```
<div id="slideshow">
            <div>
            <img src="images/1.jpg" style="width:100%;" alt="1" />
            <p>1</p>
           </div>              
           <div>
            <img src="images/2.jpg" style="width:100%;" alt="2" />
            <p>2</p>
           </div>

           <div>
            <video controls="" height="500" width="380">
              <source src="videos.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            Your browser does not support the video tag.                    
            </video>                
            <p>3</p>
           </div>
</div>
```

And my jquery code....

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

Comment: How long is your video? Because the obvious reason is that the animation is too fast.

Comment: 48 seconds long.

Comment: Well then you need to extend your animation. I would recommend you to find a slider library where you can set individual length for each slide. Ex http://www.jssor.com/

Comment: But it may be long time for images.I want only for video

Comment: Read my comment to the end, it mentions individual timing.

Comment: how to  set individual length for each slide?